# Register keyCode is deleted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input that I am parsing for a username followed by @ (@steve). It works much like Slack. When a user types '@' a dialogue with all the users is shown. When they type a 'space' then the dialogue closes. My problem is knowing when the user deletes or backspaces the @ symbol. I need to close the dialogue if this happens but I'm stuck on how to register that event. Thank you for your help and here is what I currently have:

```
$scope.keyPress = function(keyCode) {
  if(keyCode === 64) {
    $scope.usersShow = true;
  } else if(keyCode === 32){
    $scope.usersShow = false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this (although I must admit I have never even considered coding such a feature) would be to check where the cursor is, and if the text before it is an unbroken word beginning with `@` (ie. matches `/(?:^|\s)@\S+$/`) then you should show the dialogue, otherwise hide it.

Comment: Thanks for that. The feature is implemented in the chat software called Slack and has been very handy. It makes it so you can type a comment and and have different users notified by typing the @usernames anywhere in the comment. The dialogue is just to be able to click and add the user. So basically on this I can just check for any change in the input and run the regex against the current character?

Comment: How do you check where the cursor is? Is it bound to the event?

Comment: Check the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the input (or textarea) element.